# Lasagne custom filter for each layer

Tags: python, lasagne

I have investigated a lot on the Internet but I have not found an answer! Is it possible to define a custom filter for each layer in 'Lasagne' package, in python or not? (Not choose from a special filter, also you design your filter for each layer)

If yes, how and if no is there any library that can give me this ability to design a CNN (platform is not important but python or matlab is preferred)?